# AppleScript getting text from (kind) of json file

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get two value from an IP API, the geo without extra characters and "isproxy"

result is in this format :

```
Result:
"{\"ipVersion\":4,\"ipAddress\":\"8.8.8.8\",\"latitude\":37.386051,\"longitude\":-122.083847,\"countryName\":\"United States of America\",\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"timeZone\":\"-08:00\",\"zipCode\":\"94035\",\"cityName\":\"Mountain View\",\"regionName\":\"California\",\"isProxy\":false,\"continent\":\"Americas\",\"continentCode\":\"AM\"}"
```

I tried this but I can't get isProxyValue correct, in this case its return `""continent\":\"Americas""` and in my previous tried it was "n"

```
    -- New IP data
-- Set the base URL for the API
set baseURL to "https://freeipapi.com/api/json/"
set isProxy to ""
-- Example: Get information for a specific IP address
set transactionIP to "8.8.8.8" -- Replace with the IP address you want to query

-- Create the full API URL
set apiUrl to baseURL & transactionIP

-- Make the API request
set apiResponse to do shell script "curl " & quoted form of apiUrl

-- Function to extract value for a specific key from JSON
on extractFromJSON(jsonString, key)
    set keyString to "\"" & key & "\":"
    set keyValue to text ((offset of keyString in jsonString) + (length of keyString)) through -1 of jsonString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
    set keyValueList to text items of keyValue
    repeat with i from 1 to count of keyValueList
        if keyValueList's item i contains "\"" then
            set keyValue to keyValueList's item i
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\""
    return text 2 thru -2 of keyValue
end extractFromJSON

-- Extract values
set countryCode to extractFromJSON(apiResponse, "countryCode")
set isProxyValue to extractFromJSON(apiResponse, "isProxy")

return isProxyValue
if isProxyValue is equal to "false" then
    set isProxy to " = Proxy"
else
    set isProxy to " = Not a Proxy"
end if

return countryCode & isProxy
```

Comment: Do you specifically need AppleScript for this, or would using `jq` in the shell be an option as well?

Comment: in the ideal, I don't want to install any third party tool

Comment: Are you aware of https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/json-helper-for-applescript/id453114608 ?

Comment: `sed` isn't the best tool for JSON, but neither is AppleScript. Something like `j=$(curl -s https://freeipapi.com/api/json/8.8.8.8); sed -E -n 's/.*latitude":([0-9\.\-]*),.*/\1/p' <<< $j; sed -E -n 's/.*longitude":([0-9\.\-]*),.*/\1/p' <<< $j; sed -E -n 's/.*isProxy":([a-z]*),.*/\1/p' <<< $j` should work.

Comment: Regular AppleScript may not be very good at it, but AppleScriptObjC can use Cocoa to serialize JSON into a NSDictionary, where you can just get the value for a key or keyPath.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript can parse JSON strings natively, we can borrow this ability using a snippet of JXA.  I've also elected to call the API using an Objective-C method, which, at the very least, results in cleaner-looking code (although I see AskDifferent's syntax highlighting still doesn't cope well with apostrophes).

The code below contains one main handler, `APIResponse`, which takes a labelled *`for`* parameter that should be passed either an IP address to perform a look-up.   If passed an empty string or any non-string value (e.g. `missing value`, `null`, `me`) then it sends an API request to the same endpoint but without a payload, which their documentation indicates that the look-up will then be performed against the user's own IP address.

Therefore, I decided to perform a look-up on theirs, by calling the handler like so:

```
set response to the APIResponse for "104.21.94.136"
```

This handler itself contains another handler embedded within the `API` script object, called `response:`.  It takes a single argument, which will be the JSON string that gets returned by an API request.  This JSON string is then inserted into a JavaScript call to `JSON.parse(...)` as the argument.  In a JavaScript environment, it would return an `Object` populated with key-value entries.  This directly "bridges" to an AppleScript `record`, containing properties and values.

The overall return value of the script is currently this AppleScript `record` that represents the response to an API request.  However, the lines immediately preceding this extract all the individual response fields and assigns their values to top-level variables with corresponding names.

Thus, you can replace the final line:

```
return the response
```

with one the returns the specific fields you're after, e.g.:

```
return [countryCode, isProxy]
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -s s
#･･････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････#
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions
#･･････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････#
property text item delimiters : {}
property nil : a reference to missing value
#･･････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････#
set response to APIResponse for "104.21.94.136"

set [ipVersion, ipAddress, isProxy, latitude, longitude, timeZone, ¬
        countryName, countryCode, zipCode, cityName, regionName, ¬
        continent, continentCode] to response's [ipVersion, ipAddress, ¬
        isProxy, latitude, longitude, timeZone, countryName, countryCode, ¬
        zipCode, cityName, regionName, continent, continentCode]

return the response
#･･････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････#
## HANDLERS:
on APIResponse for ip_addr
        script API
                property IPv4 address : ({} & ip_addr & "")'s string 1
                property baseURL : "https://freeipapi.com"
                property endpoint : "/api/json/" & IPv4 address
                property requestURL : baseURL & endpoint
                
                on response:(JSON as string)
                        run script "JSON.parse(" & quoted form ¬
                                of JSON & ");" in "JavaScript"
                end response:
        end script
        
        API's response:(my (NSString's stringWithContentsOfURL:(the ¬
                URLWithString_(the requestURL of the API) of my NSURL) ¬
                encoding:(my NSUTF8StringEncoding) |error|:nil))
end APIResponse
#･･････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････････#
```